# Java - Storing Sorted List Values in Memory

Tags: java, list, sorting, memory, hashmap

Quick Explanation:

I have a Hashmap that stores lists in different orders depending on their sortType. I want this to be stored in memory so that I don't have to sort each list on runtime, many times over which would be causing a lot of strain on CPU usage.

Currently I have a general HashMap that stores all items with their corresponding ID...

```
private Map<String, Cosmetic> cosmeticIDs;
```

I then store each of these IDs in a list which has been sorted based on the sortType and inserted into a HashMap as shown below...

```
public enum SortType {
    ALPHABETICALLY,
    ALPHABETICALLY_REVERSE,
    RARITY,
    RARITY_REVERSE;
}
```

```
        // List of Strings is the ID of each item
    private EnumMap<SortType, List<String>> availableTrailsIDs;
    private EnumMap<SortType, List<String>> availableGadgetsIDs;
    private EnumMap<SortType, List<String>> availableSuitsIDs;
    private EnumMap<SortType, List<String>> availablePetsIDs;
```

I then use the following to get the sorted map on runtime:

```
List<String> gadgets = availableGadgets.get(sortType);

for (String gadgetID : gadgets.subList(min, max)) {
   Cosmetic gadget = CosmeticHandler.getInstance().getCosmeticFromID(gadgetID);
   // LOAD GADGETS IN ORDER
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? It seems like this a massive design flaw and is wasting a ton of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `SortedSet#subSet` & `NavigableSet#descendingSet`

Use [`SortedSet#subSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/SortedSet.html#subSet(E,E)) & [`NavigableSet#descendingSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html#descendingSet()). Both of these methods return a *view* onto the original set, without creating a separate collection.

The concrete class [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) implements both of those interfaces. (`TreeSet` also implements [`SequencedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/SequencedSet.html) now in Java 21+. See [JEP 431](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431).)

```
public enum SortType {
    ALPHABETICALLY(new TreeSet<String>(/*you can have custom comparator Comparator.comparing... so you can use the cosmetic*/)) {

        @Override
        public Set<String> getSubSet(String min, String max) {
            return set.subSet(min, max);
        }
        
    },
    ALPHABETICALLY_REVERSE(ALPHABETICALLY.set) {

        @Override
        public Set<String> getSubSet(String min, String max) {
            return set.descendingSet().subSet(min, max);
        }
        
    },
    RARITY(new TreeSet<String>(/*you can have custom comparator Comparator.comparing... so you can use the cosmetic*/)) {

        @Override
        public Set<String> getSubSet(String min, String max) {
            return set.subSet(min, max);
        }
        
    },
    RARITY_REVERSE(RARITY.set) {

        @Override
        public Set<String> getSubSet(String min, String max) {
            return set.descendingSet().subSet(min, max);
        }
        
    };
    
    protected TreeSet<String> set;
    
    private SortType(TreeSet<String> set) {
        this.set = set;
    }
    
    public void add(String o) {
        set.add(o);
    }
    
    public abstract Set<String> getSubSet(String min, String max);

}
```

you have to retain now only to copy of the set, depending on the order adding itemes to both the TreeSets.

Comment: By the way, in Java 21+ you can call [`SortedSet#reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/SortedSet.html#reversed()) to get the equivalent of calling `descendingSet`, a a reverse-ordered view of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

An easy improvement would be to cut down on the number of lists you store. Remove `XXX_REVERSE` and iterate backwards if you need items in reverse order.

For example:

```java
public enum SortType {
    ALPHABETICALLY,
    RARITY
}
```

```java
public static void loadGadgets(SortType sortType, boolean reverseOrder) {
    List<String> gadgets = availableGadgets.get(sortType);
    List<String> gadgetSub = gadgets.subList(min, max);

    // Set up iteration order.
    int startIndex;
    int endIndex;
    int step;
    if (reverseOrder) {
        startIndex = gadgetSub.size() - 1;
        endIndex = - 1;
        step = - 1;
    } else {
        startIndex = 0;
        endIndex = gadgetSub.size();
        step = 1;
    }

    for (int i = startIndex; i != endIndex; i += step) {
        // Get gadget by index.
        String gadgetID = gadgetSub.get(i);
        Cosmetic gadget = CosmeticHandler.getInstance().getCosmeticFromID(gadgetID);
        // LOAD GADGETS IN ORDER
    }
}
```

If you need to maintain the separate lists for `trails`, `gadgets`, etc., then the `EnumMaps` are a decent way to store them and index-based iterating, though chunky, has very readable intent without adding additional complexity.